# Odoo 15 Inherit And Change String of Button in PoS

Tags: xml, odoo, qweb, odoo-15

Hope everything is well for you :D

Currently i'm trying to inherit and edit a customer button from Point of Sale in Odoo 15 to change it's string from "Customer" to "Pelanggan".

[image]

From what i read, there are a huge changes between version 15 and previous version. In previous version, to inherit the button from the PoS XML file we can use `t-extend`, `t-jquery` and `t-operation="replace"` tags but it seems like its no longer work in latest because in [official documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html#old-inheritance-mechanism-deprecated) it says deprecated.

The closest things i can get is by using this code below, following example from the [Documentation](https://t-inherit) :

```
<t t-inherit="point_of_sale.ActionpadWidget" t-inherit-mode="extension">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='actionpad']" position="replace">
        <span>Pelanggan</span>
    </xpath>
</t>
```

But the result are removing entire actionpad instead :

[image]

How is it possible to inherit certain button and rewrite it with another string in version 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you used targets the [containing div](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/xml/Screens/ProductScreen/ActionpadWidget.xml#L5-L26).

To replace the customer button string, you can target the [last `t`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/xml/Screens/ProductScreen/ActionpadWidget.xml#L12-L14) inside the first button

***Example***

```
<xpath expr="//div[hasclass('actionpad')]/button[hasclass('set-customer')]/t[3]" position="replace">
    <t t-else="">Pelanggan</t>
</xpath>
```